# Need to make other partition in Windows 8 after C

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning

I recently purchased a Dell Laptop with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. It has only a C: drive plus a recovery partition. I need to make another partition after C: to use for my data.  Will the recovery partition be disturbed if a new partition is made?

Answer (score -1):

A live CD like gparted will do this for you: gparted.org/livecd.php.  First error check and defrag your c drive, download the iso and burn to cd, boot from the cd and follow the instructions.